# Stronger binomial theorem

Tags: inequality, binomial-theorem

currently I am stocked at proving an inequality. Since it is very specific I don't want to go into detail, but it has a form like this:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} f(i)^{i} g(i)^{n-i}$$

where f and g are polynomial functions mapping into $(0,1)$.
Sure it is possible to bound g and f and then apply the binomial theorem, but the bound I receive is not good enough.

Are there any other known inequalities I can apply, which are stronger than the method above, without using an upper bound for $ f(i)$ and $g(i)$?

Thank you

EDIT

Exact form:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} \Big( 1-\frac{n-i}{n} \Big)^i \Big( \frac{i}{n^2}\Big)^{n-i}
$$

Comment: Binomial theorem isn't an inequality, and to get "good" bounds you need to be more specific on what's good for you and perhaps also the exact polynomial forms. Potentially a lot of inequalities could apply.

Comment: I've edited the post. You can find the exact form there.

Comment: $g(i)=i/2$ does not belong to $(0,1)$ if $i>2$ so it might be that your first bound was wrong.

Comment: sorry there was a missing n

Comment: ok, then you can already refine your bound by using that $g(i)\leq 1/n$ for every $i=1,...,n$. Also note that $1-(n-i)/n = i/n$.

Comment: But then the only way I can bound $i/n$ is 1

Comment: This can be rewritten $n^{-2n}\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \binom nii^nn^i$ it's definitely simpler, but I don't know a closed form either.